# ContextMenu on Multiple Buttons to change text of button being right clicked

Tags: vb.net, right-click, contextmenustrip

I have multiple buttons on my VB.net form. I have a single ContextMenuStrip and I have assigned it to all the buttons. I can't seem to figure out how to set the button text to the menu selection based on which button I right clicked on.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
Private Sub PuTTYToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PuTTYToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        btn.Text = "PuTTY"
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to save a reference or indicator in the Menu Opening event

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix... I modified to do that but I am stuck. My menu items have sub items... when I click a sub item, it updates my button to the "parent" menu item name..

`Private Sub ButtonMenuList1_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ButtonMenuList1.ItemClicked
        Dim contextMenu = DirectCast(sender, ContextMenuStrip)
        Dim btn = DirectCast(contextMenu.SourceControl, Button)

        Dim toolStripItem = e.ClickedItem
        btn.Text = toolStripItem.Text
    End Sub`

Comment: There is a bug that `SourceControl` wont reliably hold onto the control you set it to.  Just use a form level var (eg `mnuBtn`) which you set in the menu opening event.  Then use that in your clicks

Comment: If I remember correctly, `SourceControl` works fine for top-level menu items but anything below that will show it as `Nothing`.  I have always done as @Plutonix suggests when I've needed this functionality.